# debug Angular application server side

Tags: angular, angular-cli, webstorm, breakpoints, serve

How to run serverside of Angular application with debugger? I have application, which is run with `ng serve` command and I am using WebStorm on Windows.

I set `start` in `package.json` to `ng serve` and run `start` command in debug mode. But I have impression that debugger doesn't pause on breakpoints.

Have I did it in correct way?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need running `start` in debug mode, unless you need debugging angular cli. To debug your application, you have to create a [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.2/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) run configuration with http://localhost:4200 **URL**, run your app with `start` and then debug the configuration sbove. See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-angular-apps/

Comment: Sorry for mistake in question, meant server side debugging not client side.

Comment: so, would you like to debug `ng` an not your Angular application?

Comment: I am total newbie to Angular i did not write anything in Angular yet. I have aplication an need to exchange only one function server side with my node implementation. But can not get breakponits there or see added `console.log`\`s. I see my question is bad formulated I will delete it in future.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to extend your Webstorm configuration to be able to debug your Angular application in Webstorm (see [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-angular-apps/)).

Otherwise you can debug the application with the DevTools of your browser. My experience shows that this has a better performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to debug typescript code, the easiest way is to open up your sources tab in your browser. This may differ from browser to browser, but this is how Chrome works.

From here, go into the sources tab and navigate to the specific file that your working on. Set a break point in the left hand side, restart the page and it should break on the break point you set. I'm not exactly sure how it will react with Webstorm, but it may debug in the browser and in the IDE (which can get slightly annoying).

Comment: Sorry for mistake in question, meant server side debugging not client side.

Comment: @jabone Can you fix the question?